# Rails precompile error: syntax Error at line: 1, column 38 for bootstrap import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, deployment, bootstrap-5, precompile

When running: `rake assets:precompile RUBY_ENV=production` or when it automatically precompiles for deployment it gets this error message:

```
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/protocol.rb:66: warning: already initialized constant Net::ProtocRetryError
/home/tbtonner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/net-protocol-0.1.3/lib/net/protocol.rb:68: warning: previous definition of ProtocRetryError was here
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/protocol.rb:206: warning: already initialized constant Net::BufferedIO::BUFSIZE
/home/tbtonner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/net-protocol-0.1.3/lib/net/protocol.rb:208: warning: previous definition of BUFSIZE was here
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/protocol.rb:503: warning: already initialized constant Net::NetPrivate::Socket
/home/tbtonner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/net-protocol-0.1.3/lib/net/protocol.rb:504: warning: previous definition of Socket was here
Compiling...
Compilation failed:
Hash: 0d1853ed830e6c3e5bae
Version: webpack 4.46.0
Time: 3670ms
Built at: 08/22/2022 4:30:23 PM
 3 assets
Entrypoint application = js/application-c19864950abec08bba5f.js js/application-c19864950abec08bba5f.js.map
 [8] ./node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/dom-utils/listScrollParents.js + 2 modules 1.84 KiB {0} [built]
     |    3 modules
[13] ./node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/dom-utils/getCompositeRect.js + 5 modules 2.41 KiB {0} [built]
     |    6 modules
[14] ./node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/dom-utils/getCommonOffsetParent.js + 2 modules 2.74 KiB {0} [built]
     |    3 modules
[15] ./node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/utils/validateModifiers.js + 1 modules 3.43 KiB {0} [built]
     |    2 modules
[16] ./node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/dom-utils/addClientRectMargins.js + 1 modules 826 bytes {0} [built]
     |    2 modules
[17] multi ./app/frontend/packs/application.js ./app/frontend/packs/application.scss 40 bytes {0} [built]
[18] ./app/frontend/packs/application.scss 664 bytes {0} [built]
[20] ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--6-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-3!./app/frontend/packs/application.scss 1.9 KiB {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
[21] ./app/frontend/packs/application.js + 12 modules 198 KiB {0} [built]
     | ./app/frontend/packs/application.js 899 bytes [built]
     | ./app/frontend/js/bootstrap_js_files.js 402 bytes [built]
     |     + 11 hidden modules
    + 13 hidden modules

ERROR in ./app/frontend/packs/application.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--6-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-3!./app/frontend/packs/application.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
ParserError: Syntax Error at line: 1, column 38
    at /home/tbtonner/woodvilla/app/frontend/packs/application.scss:6:67385
    at Parser.error (/home/tbtonner/woodvilla/node_modules/postcss-values-parser/lib/parser.js:127:11)
    at Parser.operator (/home/tbtonner/woodvilla/node_modules/postcss-values-parser/lib/parser.js:162:20)
    at Parser.parseTokens (/home/tbtonner/woodvilla/node_modules/postcss-values-parser/lib/parser.js:245:14)
    at Parser.loop (/home/tbtonner/woodvilla/node_modules/postcss-values-parser/lib/parser.js:132:12)
    at Parser.parse (/home/tbtonner/woodvilla/node_modules/postcss-values-parser/lib/parser.js:51:17)
    at parse (/home/tbtonner/woodvilla/node_modules/postcss-custom-properties/index.cjs.js:47:30)
    at /home/tbtonner/woodvilla/node_modules/postcss-custom-properties/index.cjs.js:333:24
    at /home/tbtonner/woodvilla/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:194:18
    at /home/tbtonner/woodvilla/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:139:18
    at Rule.each (/home/tbtonner/woodvilla/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:105:16)
    at Rule.walk (/home/tbtonner/woodvilla/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:135:17)
    at /home/tbtonner/woodvilla/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:152:24
    at Root.each (/home/tbtonner/woodvilla/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:105:16)
    at Root.walk (/home/tbtonner/woodvilla/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:135:17)
    at Root.walkDecls (/home/tbtonner/woodvilla/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:192:19)
    at transformProperties (/home/tbtonner/woodvilla/node_modules/postcss-custom-properties/index.cjs.js:330:8)
    at Object.syncTransform [as plugin] (/home/tbtonner/woodvilla/node_modules/postcss-custom-properties/index.cjs.js:522:5)
    at /home/tbtonner/woodvilla/node_modules/postcss-preset-env/index.js:459:97
 @ ./app/frontend/packs/application.scss 2:26-228
 @ multi ./app/frontend/packs/application.js ./app/frontend/packs/application.scss
```

The line it's pointing to as a syntax error is `@import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap';` in `packs/application.scss`.

Bootstrap is fully working with `rails s` and `bin/webpack-dev-server` running, so I'm unsure why it's throwing a syntax error here when precompiling the assets.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade bootstrap, better explanation here: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/3188

Comment: That was an issue with 5.1, it was fixed in 5.1.2 but it's back with 5.2.0 and hasn't been patched yet.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in Bootstrap 5.2.0 that is causing this. I had the exact same error, line 1 col 38.

See [this issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/36851) and [this one](https://github.com/ackama/rails-template/issues/315). My temporary solution was to downgrade Bootstrap to 5.1.3 while this is not fixed ([the problem was patched in 5.1.2 (the first highlight)](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/tag/v5.1.2) but is present in 5.2.0).

Edit: [This PR](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/37079) fixes it. It should be released with 5.2.1.

Edit2: Bootstrap 5.2.1 is [now released](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/tag/v5.2.1) and should fix this.